# Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve bundle revision com.springsource.org.apache.axis

Tags: spring, osgi

Getting below error when im trying to run a OSGI bundle. Any clues will be really appreciate.

```
ERROR: Bundle com.springsource.org.apache.axis [15] Error starting mvn:
org.apache.axis/com.springsource.org.apache.axis/1.4.0 (
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve 
bundle revision com.springsource.org.apache.axis [15.0] because it is exposed to 
package 'javax.activation' from bundle revisions com.springsource.javax.activation 
[14.0] and org.apache.felix.framework [0] via two dependency chains.
```

Chain 1:

```
com.springsource.org.apache.axis [15.0] import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=
 javax.activation)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) | export: 
 osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation com.springsource.javax.activation [14.0]
```

Chain 2:

```
 com.springsource.org.apache.axis [15.0] import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=
 javax.xml.soap)(version>=0.0.0)) | export: osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.soap; 
 uses:=javax.activation export: osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation 
 org.apache.felix.framework [0]) 
 org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Uses constraint violation. 
 Unable to resolve bundle revision 
 com.springsource.org.apache.axis [15.0] because it is exposed to package 
 'javax.activation' from bundle revisions com.springsource.javax.activation [14.0] 
  and org.apache.felix.framework [0] via two dependency chains.
```

Chain 1:

`com.springsource.org.apache.axis [15.0] import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) | export: osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation com.springsource.javax.activation [14.0]`

Chain 2:

`com.springsource.org.apache.axis [15.0] import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.soap)(version>=0.0.0)) | export: osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.soap; uses:=javax.activation export: osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation org.apache.felix.framework [0] at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3980) at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037) at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1291) at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the *com.springsource.javax.activation* bundle from your list of bundles. 
If you need this special javax.activation bundle because of a special version, you'd need to make sure your own Imports are correct for the version. 
Now that you are using the *com.springsource.** bundles, those are pretty "OLD" and not maintained anymore I'd suggest to switch over to:
A) The official jars (like javax.activation) where the latest version is already a OSGi ready bundle
B) use ServiceMix wrapped bundles, the Apache ServiceMix Team provides a lot of OSGi ready bundles which aren't available from the originators.